# Increase the space between the caption and main text for a table at the bottom

Tags: tables, captions

My floating tables have their caption above them. I noticed that, when tables happen to be at the bottom of the page, the vertical space between the main text and the table (i.e. between the main text and the caption) is too small. I tried to solve the problem by setting `belowskip` (which in this case, being the caption above, should set the space above the caption). This solves my problem when the table is at the bottom, but the space is added also when the table is at the top of the page, which is the most common situation.

Is there a way to set the additional space above the caption/table only when the table is at the bottom? (I never put the table with the `h` option, but ideally the solution should work for this case too).

I guess `\vspace` at the beginning of the table environment, before the caption, would do the job, but I **don't** want to add it by hand.

Comment: floats are typeset at the  point they are entered but re-inserted later so by default this is not possible. You can increase `\textfloatsep`

Comment: I see, but is it possible to set this length differently depending on the type of float and whether the float is at the top or at the bottom

Comment: er, define "possible"...  Latex source can be redefined at runtime so yes, in theory but it is not a feature provided by default or easy to add

Comment: You can add space at the top of a "bottom" table by placing `\vspace*{...}` at the top of the `table` environment.